# install a EXCLUDE_FROM_ALL subdirectory

Tags: cmake

I have a project `A` that uses some targets defined in project `B`. Hence I did `add_subdirectory(<PATH_TO B> EXCLUDE_FROM_ALL)` to include the subdirectory. Now, I create install targets using components and there are some install components in `A` that require targets from `B` too. But, due to `EXCLUDE_FROM_ALL`, the `cmake_install.cmake` for `A` does not include that of `B`. How should I approach this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can install specific targets defined in subdirectory `CMakeLists.txt` after cmake 3.13.

Before 3.13, user may use

```
add_subdirectory(path/to/sub_dir EXCLUDE_FROM_ALL)
target_link_libraries(your_target PRIVATE your_sub_dir_target)
...
install(SCRIPT ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/path/to/sub_dir/cmake_install.cmake)
```

with `EXCLUDE_FROM_ALL`, the `your_sub_dir_target` will not be included in the `ALL` target, then the install command will not be called for your sub_dir, you'll need to manually do it.